# Jersey Bean Validation: Unable to initialize 'jakarta.el.ExpressionFactory'

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jetty, jersey-3.0

I have implemented a REST service using Jersey and wanted to use Bean Validation. When I add the bean validation maven dependency for Jersey (jersey-bean-validation), the webapp breaks on startup due to an error:

```
HV000183: Unable to initialize 'jakarta.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath, or use ParameterMessageInterpolator instead
```

I searched around and found older solutions mentioning including missing dependencies, such as this question:

[javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to load 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386771/javax-validation-validationexception-hv000183-unable-to-load-javax-el-express)

but the dependencies are outdated in my case. Also, when looking at the dependency tree:

```
[INFO] org.example:valtest:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.25.0-GA:compile
[INFO] \- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-bean-validation:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO]    +- jakarta.inject:jakarta.inject-api:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO]    +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:7.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO]    +- jakarta.el:jakarta.el-api:jar:4.0.0:compile
[INFO]    \- org.glassfish:jakarta.el:jar:4.0.0:compile
```

I can see at the very bottom that the el-api and el libraries are included as transitive dependencies of the jersey-bean-validation library already.

I put a breakpoint into ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator to find out the cause of this, and when the ExpressionFactory is getting instanciated, an exception is thrown:

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: jakarta.el.ExpressionFactory: org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl not a subtype
```

I don't know where that comes from. I can at least create an ExpressionFactory as expected using:

```
ExpressionFactory.newInstance()
```

I have created a very simple example project that uses the same Jersey+Jetty setup with maven that I use in my project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dcvief9dlqk648m/valtest.zip?dl=0
It can be run with `mvn jetty:run` and it should display a message on http://localhost:8080/test.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr;

The Jetty Maven plugin pulls in a conflicting dependency. The dependency deals with JSP. If you don't have any need for JSP in your application, I think the following solution should be safe. You just need to exclude the bad dependency

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.2</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jasper</groupId>
                    <artifactId>apache-el</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

---

So how the `ExpressionFactory` is found, is through a [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html). The `org.glassfish:jakarta.el` jar doesn't have the required `META-INF/services` file to be found through the `ServiceLoader`. But after the `ServiceLoader` fails, other options will be tried. So ultimately, the jar's [`ExpressionFactoryImpl`](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/el-ri/blob/4.0.0/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/el/ExpressionFactoryImpl.java) *will* be found. But the problem is that the Jetty Maven plugin also pulls in an implementation, which *does* have the `META-INF/services` file. So that is the implementation that will be used.

After some debugging, and stepping into [the ServiceLoader code](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/el-ri/blob/7c547f057fd8a20825d26a1aa48fbbb3e65db7c5/api/src/main/java/jakarta/el/FactoryFinder.java#L93), I came across this error when the class was found:

```java
"jakarta.el.ExpressionFactory: org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl not a subtype"
```

So I created a new Maven project and added the jetty-maven-plugin as a dependency. After searching through all the jars, I found the `o.a.e.ExpressionFactoryImpl` class. It was in the `apache-el` jar that Jetty pulled in. The weird part is that the class actually does implement the `jakarta.el.ExpressionFactory`. I thought that maybe the problem was that it implemented the old `javax` class, but that wasn't the case. I'm not completely sure why this causes an error. But after getting that out of the way, it began to work.

#### Another option if removing `apache-el` is not desired

One thing I tried before I got the above solution was to try to manually add the `META-INF/services` file to the the `org.glassfish:jakarta.el` jar. What I did was the following

```sh
cd ~/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jakarta.el/4.0.0
mkdir -p META-INF/services
echo com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl > META-INF/services/jakarta.el.ExpressionFactory
jar uf jakarta.el-4.0.0.jar META-INF/services/jakarta.el.ExpressionFactory

# You may want to make a copy of the original dependency before you do this
# so you can easily revert back to the original if needed.
```

This may not be a desirable solution either, but it worked.

If you need the `apache-el`, you can also try to replace it with the `org.glassfish:jakarta.el` and see if that works. I haven't tried it yet, but I'm not sure if Jetty will run into similar problems with a different implementation or not.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! It works now as expected.