# Override spring web mvc's default Hibernate Validator

Tags: java, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

Spring is using the default validator factory provided by hibernate factory. However, I do not want to include an Expression Language dependency.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54750045/1810962) recommends avoiding using the default factory by using this code:

```
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ParameterMessageInterpolator;

private static final Validator VALIDATOR =
  Validation.byDefaultProvider()
    .configure()
    .messageInterpolator(new ParameterMessageInterpolator())
    .buildValidatorFactory()
    .getValidator();
```

That works well when I have a reference to VALIDATOR, but I'm not sure how to tell spring to use the above instead of the `OptionalValidatorFactoryBean` which extends `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` that I think is filled in with the validator from `Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory()` based on the javadoc from [LocalValidatorFactoryBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/LocalValidatorFactoryBean.html)

In summary, how do I replace spring's default `Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory()` with `Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure().messageInterpolator(new ParameterMessageInterpolator()).buildValidatorFactory().getValidator()`
so that I can avoid the dependency on Expression Language.

Comment: Are you wanting to validate like Controller methods and/or Command beans?

Comment: I'm validating http requests that are converted by spring into beans. The beans have Bean Validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at [Configuring a Bean Validation Provider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring) for some discussion of the Validation Provider mechanism, and, for example, [Spring-driven Method Validation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring-method), to then inject that as a default method-validation bean.

```xml
    <bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor">  
        <property name="validatorFactory" ref="myValidatorFactory"/>  
    </bean>
```

(I did this kind of thing with Spring 4.x, on WebSphere Application Server, [here](https://dougbreaux.github.io/2018/05/23/springmvc-jsr303-websphere.html).)

Comment: Thank you. I will look through this and try it out tomorrow. I will report back with the results here.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @dbreaux 's answer I went through the docs and came up with this solution:

```
@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    localValidatorFactoryBean.setMessageInterpolator(new ParameterMessageInterpolator());
    return localValidatorFactoryBean;
}
```

I no longer need the Expression Language dependency and my validation is working with Hibernate Validator `5.2.5.Final`.

However, due to a security issue, I had to upgrade to `6.0.22.Final` and switched to the below which is really close to @dbreaux 's. I also had to add @Validated to the @Controller.

```
@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    MethodValidationPostProcessor bean = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    bean.setValidator(Validation.byDefaultProvider()
            .configure()
            // We must use ParameterMessageInterpolator so that we do not need to add a dependency
            // on Java Expression Language which is a potential security vulnerability.
            // See https://securitylab.github.com/research/bean-validation-RCE/ for more info.
            .messageInterpolator(new ParameterMessageInterpolator())
            .buildValidatorFactory()
            .getValidator());
    return bean;
}
```